# How to get data from concatenated strings in one cell to another table in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

for my use case, I have a **Google survey that is connected to a main Google Sheet**.

**The survey** has a 2 questions: 1. Name, 2. Multiple Choice from 1-31 (days of a month).
My survey results come into a by Google survey/Forms automatically generated table in Google Sheets with 2 columns: 'Name', and 'Which days?'. The 'Which Days?' column is has cells with a concatenated list of strings (e.g. '1, 3, 6, 8, 11').

**The main Google Sheet** has following structure: The first column is 'Name' that just imports the name from the Typeform Sheet (this works fine).
The remaining columns represent the days of the month (so up to 31 columns from 1-31).
Under each column, there are checkboxes.

The idea is that the checkboxes will automatically check according to the results from the Typeform (instead of checkboxes, we could also use colored cells if that is easier).

**The problem**:
How can I automatically get the data from the concatenated cell 'Which Days?' (e.g. '1, 3, 6, 8, 11') to the main Google Sheet (so that columns '1', '3', ..., '11' are checked/colored)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula on cell B2 of your main sheet (assume Sheet1 is your survey sheet and Sheet2 is your main sheet):

```
=IF(iferror(match(CELL("address",B2),ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(ROW(B2),1+split(Sheet1!$B2,","))),0),0),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Then drag right and down to the end of the table.

**Sample:**

[image]

[image]

**Explanation:**

`SPLIT` creates an array of numbers based on your input delimited by commas.

`ADDRESS` creates a string of cell references. `ARRAYFORMULA` extends this to an array.

`MATCH` returns a valid value if the `CELL` reference of the cell position exists on the other table, else it will return error.

`IF` and `IFERROR` will return true or false depending on the value of MATCH.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I can comprehend the formula but I still failed to use it. There was an error.

I also tried to identically reproduce your example but it still showed the same errors: 1. Formular parse error, and 2. Invalid: This cell's contents violate its validation rule.

Maybe I made a mistake regarding the data validation setting? That might explain error 2...

Comment: Try to format the cells as checkboxes. Insert -> Checkbox

Comment: mh. Does not work either.

Did you insert the formula into B2 and then insert a checkbox?

After deleting the data validation, the parsing error (#ERROR!) still remains..

Comment: The order doesn't matter, when the cells are not in checkboxes they should display as a true or false table. Maybe you're in a country that uses semicolons as formula separators. Try replacing the commas with semicolons.

Comment: Nice! Now it works.

Just a little problem occurred: My Sheet2 has 2 additional columns on the left handside. And apparently, the checkboxes are shifted 2 positions to the left. Hence, under column 1, the checkbox actually displays the value for column 3.

Comment: This is different from your original question, but you can use ````2+split(Sheet1!$B2,",")```` depending on how many columns your shift is.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(COLUMN(B:K)-1&"", 
 "^"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A10:A12, A1:B3, 2, 0)), " ", ), ",", "$|^")&"$"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you change the formula if both tables were in separate sheets?

Comment: @2stefan2000 you just change ranges to match your sheet names and sheet ranges

Comment: @2stefan2000 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m0dDqUIxLt6a858qvU-at6Fwssh36FTdGhnm-RqZyD4/edit#gid=416077784

Comment: thank you for the link! I have already implemented the other proposed solution but still appreciate it.